# Plugging two monitors into my laptop

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

On my DELL laptop I have two video outputs(HDMI and VGA). I plugged one monitor into the HDMI port and it works perfectly. I unplugged it and plugged it into the VGA port. This also works perfectly. What I didn't try is plugging in two monitors at the same time. My laptop has 8 GB RAM. Will it work if I plug two monitors at the same time? Would this bad for my laptop's GPU?

Comment: Why not try plugging in two monitors and find out?

Comment: To get any help you will need to supply the model name/number of your Dell laptop. Some allow only one video output to be connected.

Comment: @Tog it is DELL Inspiron N7110

Comment: @techie007 I need my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you plug in the monitor and get the laptop to display both on the single external monitor and on the laptop screen at the same time in an extended desktop mode? That would be partial evidence that it would also work with two external monitors (and nothing on the laptop screen).

However, if you are trying to get two monitors AND the laptop display to work at the same time, the only way to test it is to try, and it is less likely to work without a good graphics card. I concur that it's not likely to harm your laptop.

(I played around a fair bit with multi-monitor configurations on my old dell laptop with vga + hdmi, from what I remember I could get two external displays to work, but not two external displays plus the laptop display).

Answer (score 2):

This should work, depending on the model of the video card.  No, this is not bad for your laptop's GPU.